# How to detect a invalid input and put the user into a loop until an acceptable answer is typed?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to get the user to type on letters and return numbers as invalid inputs only.

This is my code, I'm still unclear about the ValueError as if I run the code and type in letters it'll come out as an invalid input but if I put in numbers it comes in as valid.

```
while True:
    try:

        name = int(input("What is your name? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid response. Letters only please.")
        continue
    else:

        break

    correctName = input("Your name is...'" + (name) + "', is this correct? \n Please use 'Y' as yes and 'N' as no.\n")
    if correctName == "Y":
        print("Thank you..!")
```

Comment: what do you mean by "type on letters and return numbers as invalid inputs only"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int(input())` will expect an integer as an input, so when you type your name (unless you're name wholly consists of numbers), you will get a `ValueError` like you're experiencing now. Instead, you can use `str(input())` to get the user input, then use the `str.isdigit()` method to check if it's a number.

```
name = str(input("What is your name? "))
if name.isdigit():
    print("Invalid response. Letters only please.")
    continue
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try regex to check if a string contains a number:

```
bool(re.search(r'\d', name))
```

`\d` will matches for digits [0-9].

it will return **True** if the string contains a number.

full code:

```
import re
while True:
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        if bool(re.search(r'\d', name)):
            print("Invalid response. Letters only please.")
        else:
            correctName = input("Your name is...'" + (name) + "', is this correct? \n Please use 'Y' as yes and 'N' as no.\n")
            if correctName == "Y":
                print("Thank you..!")
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python3

```
while True:
  name = input()
  if name.isalpha():
    break
```

For Python2

```
while True:
  name = str(input())
  if name.isalpha():
    break
```